# Cannot open Cosmos DB documents in storage explorer

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

I cannot seem to open Cosmos DB documents in storage explorer.

Tested using the latest version (1.6.2) and the previous version 1.5.0 of storage Explorer on both Mac and Windows.

[image: Hint message]

I have tried both the MongoDB and SQL API based DB's and the same issue appears. Am I missing a very simple prerequisite?

**EDIT:**

Appears I am not missing anything and this is due to a bug inside of storage explorer.

[image: ASE bug]

Comment: I assume you saw this document? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/storage-explorer

Comment: Yes.

"At this time, Azure Storage Explorer supports Cosmos accounts configured for SQL, MongoDB, Graph, and Table APIs."

Comment: i just tried it with latest storage explorer it works fine using sql api. just followed the process on the linked article. only thing I did - install azure storage explorer

Comment: Added an edit to my original post, appears to be a bug inside of storage explorer: https://github.com/Microsoft/AzureStorageExplorer/issues/971 really poor dialog 'hint' though - only found this after remembering I can view dev tools.